# Allow only one instance of a JFrame?

Tags: java, methods, uiview, jframe, instance

I have a table I made a date filter for. To open the filter a new JFrame opens with textfields. However, the JFrame is opened over a button and every time the button is clicked, a new instance of the JFrame is opened.
I tryed creating an object of the filter class and `if (!filter.isVisible()) {
filter(); }` Which makes the JFrame visible if its not visible. However even if it is visible the method is run.

Comment: Can you create an MCVE demonstrating the issue? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `public void fdatum() {
  DatumFilter a = new DatumFilter();
  centreWindow(a);
  a.setVisible(true);
 }` is run `if (a.isVisible())`

Comment: the if instruction is run in the action listener of a button